# Active Admin: How to add a custom sortable column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I'm trying to add a column to an index table, where the column's data is created dynamically when the table is loaded, and is not stored in a database.

With the following code I was able to create the column, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort it based on the dynamically created data the column will store.

```
index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :name
    column :email
    column :role
    column :company
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    if current_scope.id == 'therapists'
       column :average_rating, sortable: true do |user|
           avg = Ticket.where(format('therapist_id = %d', user.id)).average(:client_rating)
           if avg.nil?
              'No Rating'
           else
              format('%.2f', avg)
          end
       end
     end

actions
end
```

As is, the code fails because it tries to handle the sorting by pulling from a column called "average_rating" which doesn't exist. I've tried overriding the `order_by(:average_rating) do |order_clause|` and `def scoped_collection` but I couldn't get either to work.

All I need is some simple way to sort the values in the cell without trying to sort with a database query.

Comment: This is not possible with activeadmin. You will have to make an extra database column that you update with after_save and after_destroy triggers in your activerecord model. This can also be done with database triggers. Also you will have to seed the value for that extra column on the existing rows.

Comment: @SjorsBranderhorst Yeah, I ended up just adding a new column as you mentioned. However, I'm currently updating the values manually whenever ratings are provided via the web interface. I like the idea of activerecord triggers though. Seems like a cleaner approach.